# Find "seasonality" in a categorical time series in python

Tags: time-series, python, categorical-data, seasonality, hidden-markov-model

I have the following sequence:

```
states_list = ['H', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'C', 'C', 'H', 'H', 'C', 'C', 'H', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'A', 'S', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'C', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'S', 'H', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C']
```

Is there a way to find "seasonality" on this time series ?

By "seasonality" I mean, if there is a specific a specific sub-sequence of letters popping up every "n" letters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For every different letter, obtain its position in the series (1st, 2nd, ...). Take the ordered set of positions and second-difference it. If the resultant time series contains only zeros, you have found a letter that pops up every $n$ time periods. To find $n$, look at the first-differenced series; every value in it will be $n$.

I do not speak Python, but in R it would look like this:

```r
y=rep(c("A","B","C","D","E"),20) # generate a seasonal categorical time series
x=which(y=="B")                  # select the season of interest, obtain its positions
d2=diff(x,differences=2)         # 2nd differencing yields zeros only
sum(abs(d2))                     # if the sum of absolute values is zero, every element must be zero; useful for large samples where diff(x,differences=2) is too large to inspect visually
diff(x)[1]                       # the period length is 5
```

<sub>This simple program illustrates the main idea, but it is not bulletproof. It can fail in several cases. E.g. it does not notice if the letter is absent in the beginning or the end of the sequence. Include `y=c(rep("A",10),y,rep("A",10))` after the first line to see that. Fixing that should not require much effort, though.</sub>

Comment: I dont understand why take the 2nd differences. Is it because in this example you know that "B" is at the 2nd position ? Could you please explain the logic a bit more

Comment: @quant, you would take the 2nd difference regardless of which letter you were interested in. If your dataset is small, you could take the 1st difference and just visually inspect whether all the values are the same (in my example, whether all of them are equal to 5). However, if you dataset is large, you cannot inspect things visually. Then taking the 2nd difference and inspecting the sum of its absolute values solves that problem.

Comment: In the toy example where `y= ['C', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'C', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'C', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'C', 'H', 'H', 'C']` the `sum(abs(d2))` will output `1`, how is this interpreted ?

Comment: @quant, that means that the particular letter you have chosen does not repeat at fixed intervals in your sequence. There is a single instance where the interval is either shorter by 1 or longer by 1, while otherwise the letter does repeat at fixed intervals. If your sample size is small enough, you can visually inspect `diff(x)` to see which of the intervals is different from all the rest. Otherwise you can do that programmatically by `which(d2!=0)`.